# why BroadcastReceiver don't catch the Action?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am working on BroadCastReciver. There are two way to define BroadCastReciver.First one is using Java code and Second one is define in AndroidManifest.xml using . In my code second one is don't work properly.please tell where am i goes wrong.

```
public class HotelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String dActionName = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("My Rceiver ", intent.getAction());
        if (dActionName.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (dActionName.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hotelsecurity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"
        android:maxSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver 
            android:name=".HotelReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: *second one is don't work properly* means it's working and u are not getting expected results ?

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K Yap I am not getting expected result check Static registering http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2011/09/android-registering-broadcast-receiver.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your reciever should read

```
    <receiver 
        android:name="HotelReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

no dot "."

Comment: is the reciever class in the same package as the app or have you got it under a sub-package

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code inside of onCreate() for your activity,

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    HotelReceiver mReceiver = new HotelReceiver(this);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```